# Can I change a field from "not indexed" to "indexed" in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a field that has "index":"no" and i already inserted some documents,
Is there a way to change the index settings (to "analyzed" or "not_analyzed") and let the nodes crunch a little until they create the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, elasticsearch won't "reindex" internally if you update the mappings. You have to reindex all documents.

Comment: Is there a "bulk" way to do that?

Comment: The way of doing this is to "scroll" through the index and bulk index all documents. However, there are plugins that does this for you: https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex